# React-Native Android 'Network Request failed'

Tags: android, react-native, networking, request, fetch

### The issue:

I have been unable to do `fetch()` calls on the Android version of my `react-native` app recently, with the error infos being only :

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (whatwg-fetch.js:504)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:580)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:507
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:190)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:349)
    at MessageQueue.js:106
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:297)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:105)
```

I tested on iOS and it works perfectly fine. The exact same code on Android will fail no matter what I tried.

The strangest thing is that sometimes, the Android app will be able to perform 1 or 2 `fetch()` calls successfully but after that all the other will fail, or simply absolutely none will succeed. I am sure this is specific to Android as the request triggers the error before even being sent, and actually, is not even being sent.

### So far I tried:

- replacing the server address with its IP
- setting up a local JSON Server on my computer to `fetch()` on it
- tried on both an emulator and a physical device
- tried on Android 7.0 and Android 9.0

### Software versions:

- react-native: 0.57.8
- react: 16.6.3

Comment: Are you making http or https requests?

Comment: I only do https requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally managed to fix this.

Unfortunately I don't exactly know what was wrong. This whole thing happened while I was trying to setup and configure push notifications for FireBase in react-native. I started all over and now it works.
I'm sorry for whoever will experience this issue as well, but the only advice I can give you is to start fresh and read the documentation again.

Good luck !